# seaborn barplot add xticks for hue

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Seaborn barplots have an xtick for every unique value along the x coordinate. But for the hue values, there are no ticks:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["model", "time", "value"])
df["model"] = ["on"]*2 + ["off"]*2
df["time"] = ["short", "long"] * 2
df["value"] = [1, 10, 2, 4]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar = sns.barplot(data=df, x="model", hue="time", y="value", edgecolor="white")
```

[image: barplots]

Is it possible to add ticks for the hue, too?
Some of the hue colors are quite similar and I would like to add a text description, too.

Comment: Hue value is the legend, so why do you need it also as x-ticks? You can pass color palette for less similar colors.

Comment: The color coding is used in a wide variety of visualizations and needs to be consistent. In this particular plot, colors coincide that are very similar, particularly if someone should print them out in grayscale.

Comment: That is the challenge of all colored graphs! Repeating legend and x-axes may confuse graph readers. Maybe remove the redundant legend.

Comment: Well, the palette has already been established, kind of like a branding. And while you're right, adding xticks makes the legend redundant for this plot, it still serves to reiterate that overall branding. It teaches the user our colourscheme :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to be careful about the number of hues that you might have in your dataset, and the number of categories and so forth.
If you have N categories, then they are each plotted at axis coordinates 0,1,...,N-1. Then the various hues are plotted centered around this coordinate. For 2 hues like in your example, the bars are at x±0.2

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar = sns.barplot(data=df, x="model", hue="time", y="value", edgecolor="white")
ax.set_xticks([-0.2,0.2, 0.8,1.2])
ax.set_xticklabels(["on/short","on/long",'off/short','off/long'])
```

[image]

Note that I would strongly recommend that you use [`order=` and `hue_order=`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html?highlight=barplot#seaborn.barplot) in your call to `barplot()` to be sure that your labels match the bars.